# Create Android TextSwitcher with a dynamically generated Textview

Tags: android, text, textview, gallery, switch-statement

I intend to create a gallery-like `TextSwitcher` with `TextView` like this:

See image http://img441.imageshack.us/img441/5610/textp.png

When I click on a selected `TextView`, an activity will be launched.

I have read the Android API demo and many other posts, and I still cannot create anything like this. The APIdemo does not show me how to use `TextView` with `TextSwitcher`.

I believe http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-frameworks-base/android/widget/TextSwitcher.java.htm is useful, but I do not know how to use this and link to my activity `onCreate` method and add in my dynamically generated `textview`.

What would be a working solution together with the XML content?

Comment: Both links are broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to create a TextSwitcher with a dynamic TextView.

Instead, my alternative solution was to use ImageView instead. That way, I can create a gallery with horizontal scrolling as seen in the link.

Comment: The link appears to be broken.

Answer (score 1):

I got the following example in API demos
from the following path

```
C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk-windows\samples\android-10\ApiDemos\res\layout
```

and

```
C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk-windows\samples\android-10\ApiDemos\src\com\example\android\apis\view
```

**TextSwitcher1.java**

```
public class TextSwitcher1 extends Activity implements
   ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory, View.OnClickListener {

   private TextSwitcher mSwitcher;

   private int mCounter = 0;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       setContentView(R.layout.text_switcher_1);

       mSwitcher = (TextSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.switcher);
       mSwitcher.setFactory(this);

       Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
               android.R.anim.fade_in);
       Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
               android.R.anim.fade_out);
       mSwitcher.setInAnimation(in);
       mSwitcher.setOutAnimation(out);

       Button nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
       nextButton.setOnClickListener(this);

       updateCounter();
   }

   public void onClick(View v) {
       mCounter++;
       updateCounter();
   }

   private void updateCounter() {
       mSwitcher.setText(String.valueOf(mCounter));
   }

   public View makeView() {
       TextView t = new TextView(this);
       t.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
       t.setTextSize(36);
       return t;
   }
```

}

**TextSwitcher_1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2007 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text_switcher_1_next_text" />

    <TextSwitcher android:id="@+id/switcher"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yes, I have read this but this does not answer what I intend to do. I have 3 dynamically generated TextView as shown in the picture and I need to use the TextSwitcher to switch between the 3 TextView.

What the example show is only a placeholder for the counter.

Comment: hi @sunil thnks for sharing. It was really helpful for me. But I want to get the click event on this text box with the text which is viewed at that time. Could you please guide me how to achieve this. Because text view are added dynamically so I am confused on how to get its text on click to text view.